# migrate to redux from a structure like react-router huge apps example

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I implemented dynamic routing following react-router huge apps example. now i want to use redux for easy state management but have no idea how to go from here.

the file directories are all nested with different routes and the code is separated to 7 chunks. is there any example or guide on how to migrate to redux from huge apps example that react-router gives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Redux-simple-Router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router). The idea is to store your router state in the redux store.

> react-router does a great job of mapping the current URL to a component tree, and continually does so with any URL changes. This is very useful, but we really want to store this state in redux as well.

There is another package Redux-router. Which is also worth a look, but redux-simple-router does the job easily.

> redux-router is another project which solves the same problem. However, it's far more complex. Take a quick look at the code for this library—it's extremely minimal. redux-router is much bigger and more complex.

Comment: will they help with dynamic routing though?